# Hang When Loading off USB, at command sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28

Tags: 12.04, kernel, live-usb, boot-failure

I am trying to boot Ubuntu 12.04 from the live USB. It runs properly until the kernel gives an error while booting:

```
[ 32.072015] [left arrow c15af11f right Arrow] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
```

I also initially had a wireless issue that was fixed with a BIOS update. Is there any way to fix the error shown above? I an using an Acer Aspire 5002 with Windows XP professional.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some problems installing from a USB. I downloaded the ISO from the website again and noticed that it was 200mb bigger than the previous ISO I had downloaded (both were downloaded from ubuntu.com). I put the new ISO on the USB and then that worked just fine for me. It's simple but, it might be worth a shot to just try over. Worked for me.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Good luck!

Levent

Comment: Hi Levent, Thanks for the idea.  I ran it on another laptop and it worked perfectly so I am pretty sure it relates to the Acer.  I will try that in any case.  Cheers, David